# c++ problema para grabar registros en un archivo binario

Tags: c++

estoy aprendiendo a usar archivos binarios y tengo que hacer una función que cargue registros y los guarde en el archivo, el problema que estoy teniendo es que cuando termino de ingresar los datos del registro que quiero guardar me vuelve a pedir datos como para guardar otro registro, pero yo solo quiero guardar de a uno por vez.

Adjunto una imagen del problema, el último campo que debería ingresar es el de patente, luego de completarlo me vuelve a preguntar para que complete todos los campos otra vez. Mi intención es que luego del último campo guarde el registro y vuelva al menú.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

struct Poliza{ 
    char nro[4];
    char dni[11]; 
    char nombre[10];
    char apellido[10];
    char cuotaAlDia = 'V';
    char patente[8];
    char activa = 'V';
    int cantIncidentes = 0;
};

struct Incidente{
    int codigo [4];
    char fechaHora [14]; 
    char dniAsegurado [11];
    char dniOtroConductor[11];
    int nroPoliza[4];
    char calle;
    int altura;
};

void cargarPoliza (Poliza &p) 
{
    FILE *f;
    f = fopen("Asegurados.BAK", "ab+");
    if ( f==NULL )
        cout << "NO SE PUDO ABRIR EL ARCHIVO." << endl;

    cout << "Ingrese Nro de poliza (XXXX): " ;
    cin >> p.nro;
    cout << "Ingrese Nro de DNI del asegurado (XX.XXX.XXX): ";
    cin >> p.dni;
    cout << "Ingrese nombre del asegurado: ";
    cin >> p.nombre;
    cout << "Ingrese apellido del asegurado: ";
    cin >> p.apellido;
    cout << "Cuota al dia: " << p.cuotaAlDia << endl;
    cout << "Ingrese patente del vehiculo (XXXXXXXX): ";
    cin >> p.patente;
    cout << "Activa: " << p.activa << endl;
    cout << "Cantidad de incidentes: " << p.cantIncidentes << endl;

    fwrite(&p, sizeof(Poliza), 1, f);
    fclose(f);

    return;
}


void mostrarMenu ()
{
    cout << "   ***MENU***  " << endl;
    cout << "1. Cargar nueva poliza. " << endl;
    cout << "2. Desactivar poliza existente." << endl;
    cout << "3. Bucar poliza (por NRO o DNI). " << endl;
    cout << "4. Listar polizas." << endl; //preguntar formato
    cout << "5. Procesar  lote de incidentes " << endl;
    cout << "6. Mostrar polizas que no estan al dia." << endl;
    cout << "7. Finalizar jornada. " << endl;
    cout << "Esc. Salir. " << endl;

    return;
}




int main()
{
    FILE *f;
    Poliza p;
    int opcion, op2;
    char nro[4];

    mostrarMenu();
    cin >> opcion;

    do
    {
        switch(opcion)
        {
            case 1:
                cargarPoliza(p);
                break;
            case 2:
                cout << "Ingrese el nro de poliza que desea desactivar: ";
                cin >> nro;
                desactivarPoliza(p, nro, "Asegurados.BAK");
                break;
            case 3:           
                buscarPolizaXnro(p);
                break;
            case 4:
                listarPolizas("Asegurados.BAK");
                break;
            case 5:
                break;
            case 6:
                break;
            case 7:
                break;
                
        }
    }while (opcion!=27);
    return 0;
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Pues claramente no hay forma en la que el código que nos compartiste de ese problema, así que probablemente estés llamando a la función 2 veces. Procura publicar un [un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Esto significa que tienes que publicar suficiente codigo como para que yo pueda copiar, pegar en mi editor, y obtener el mismo problema. Pero no publiques todo tu programa.

Comment: Perdon!! no me di cuenta, ya lo modifique. Lo volvi a probar tal cual lo estoy pasando ahora y sigo con el mismo problema. Intente mostrar todos los campos del poliza para ver si el problema estaba ahi, pero sigue igual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes un bucle en que continuamente estás escogiendo qué hacer en base a la variable `opcion`.

```
    do
    {
        switch(opcion)
        {
            case 1:
                cargarPoliza(p);
                break;
            case 2:
                cout << "Ingrese el nro de poliza que desea desactivar: ";
                cin >> nro;
                desactivarPoliza(p, nro, "Asegurados.BAK");
                break;
            case 3:           
                buscarPolizaXnro(p);
                break;
            case 4:
                listarPolizas("Asegurados.BAK");
                break;
            case 5:
                break;
            case 6:
                break;
            case 7:
                break;
                
        }
    }while (opcion!=27);
```

Pero la variable `opcion` sólo le das valor fuera del bucle:

```
    mostrarMenu();
    cin >> opcion;

    do
    {
        ...
    }while (opcion!=27);
```

Así que siempre tomará la misma decisión, en cada vuelta, eternamente. Si quieres que cambie de idea debes poner el menú y la lectura de la variable en el bucle:

```
    do
    {
        mostrarMenu();
        cin >> opcion;

        ...
    }while (opcion!=27);
```

#### Otras cosas a tener en cuenta.

- Las cabeceras `<stdio.h>` y `<string.h>` son de [c](/questions/tagged/c) y no deben ser usadas en [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), si realmente necesitas algo de esas cabeceras (que no es tu caso) deberás usar las versiones adaptadas a C++ que son `<cstdio>` y `<cstring>` respectivamente.
- En C++ se usan flujos de datos (*stream*) para escribir en archivos o en consola.
- En la función `cargarPoliza` no necesitas pasar una `Poliza` por parámetros ya que todos los datos los manejas dentro de la función.
- No necesitas `return` al final de funciones para hacer que las funciones acaben.
- No necesitas múltiples llamadas seguidas a `std::cout` para escribir en consola, todas las llamadas consecutivas se pueden resumir en una.
- Sólo necesitas una llamada a `std::endl` por cada llamada, ya que esa instrucción envía los datos al flujo.

Si cambiamos tu código para que se parezca a C++ moderno, podría quedar así:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream> // Flujo a archivo 'f'ile 'stream'.

using namespace std;

// Las llaves vacias ({}) inicializan la formación con todo caracteres nulos (vacío)
struct Poliza {
    char nro[4]{};
    char dni[11]{}; 
    char nombre[10]{};
    char apellido[10]{};
    char cuotaAlDia = 'V';
    char patente[8]{};
    char activa = 'V';
    int cantIncidentes = 0;
};

void cargarPoliza () 
{
    Poliza p;
    cout << "Ingrese Nro de poliza (XXXX): ";
    cin >> p.nro;
    cout << "Ingrese Nro de DNI del asegurado (XX.XXX.XXX): ";
    cin >> p.dni;
    cout << "Ingrese nombre del asegurado: ";
    cin >> p.nombre;
    cout << "Ingrese apellido del asegurado: ";
    cin >> p.apellido;
    cout << "Cuota al dia: " << p.cuotaAlDia << endl;
    cout << "Ingrese patente del vehiculo (XXXXXXXX): ";
    cin >> p.patente;
    cout << "Activa: " << p.activa << endl;
    cout << "Cantidad de incidentes: " << p.cantIncidentes << endl;

    // Si no se entra en el 'if' es que no se pudo abrir el archivo.
    // ofstream es flujo a archivo de salida: 'o'utput 'f'ile 'stream'.
    if (std::ofstream f{"Asegurados.BAK", std::ios::app})
    {
        f.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&p), sizeof(p));
    }
    else
        cout << "NO SE PUDO ABRIR EL ARCHIVO." << endl;

    // No necesitas cerrar el archivo, se cierra solo al salir de la funcion
}

void listarPolizas()
{
    // Si no se entra en el 'if' es que no se pudo abrir el archivo.
    // ifstream es flujo a archivo de entrada: 'i'nput 'f'ile 'stream'.
    if (std::ifstream f{"Asegurados.BAK"})
    {
        Poliza p;
        f.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&p), sizeof(p));

        cout << "Nro de poliza (XXXX): " << p.nro << '\n';
        cout << "Nro de DNI del asegurado (XX.XXX.XXX): " << p.dni << '\n';
        cout << "nombre del asegurado: " << p.nombre << '\n';
        cout << "apellido del asegurado: " << p.apellido << '\n';
        cout << "Cuota al dia: " << p.cuotaAlDia << '\n';
        cout << "Patente del vehiculo (XXXXXXXX): " << p.patente << '\n';
        cout << "Activa: " << p.activa << '\n';
        cout << "Cantidad de incidentes: " << p.cantIncidentes << endl;
    }
    else
        cout << "NO SE PUDO ABRIR EL ARCHIVO." << endl;
}

void mostrarMenu ()
{
    cout <<
     "   ***MENU***\n"
     "1. Cargar nueva poliza.\n"
     "2. Desactivar poliza existente.\n"
     "3. Bucar poliza (por NRO o DNI).\n"
     "4. Listar polizas.\n"
     "5. Procesar  lote de incidentes\n"
     "6. Mostrar polizas que no estan al dia.\n"
     "7. Finalizar jornada.\n"
     "Esc. Salir." << endl;
}

int main()
{
    int opcion;

    do
    {
        mostrarMenu();
        cin >> opcion;

        switch(opcion)
        {
            case 1:
                cargarPoliza();
                break;
            case 2:
                break;
            case 3:           
                break;
            case 4:
                listarPolizas();
                break;
            case 5:
                break;
            case 6:
                break;
            case 7:
                break;
                
        }
    }while (opcion!=27);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!!!  Gracias por tomarte el tiempo de explicar las correcciones de forma tan fácil y detallada, me ayudan mucho.